# おこの沙汰だ - how should we translate it?

Tags: grammar, translation

How should the phrase おこの[沙汰]{さた}だ be translated in the following sentence?

> [太陽光発電]{たいようこうはつでん}に[馬鹿高]{ばかだか}い[補助金]{ほじょきん}を[出]{だ}すのは**おこの[沙汰]{さた}だ**というのが[正直]{しょうじき}なところだ。

Comment: It looks like the complete phrase 烏滸{おこ}の沙汰{さた} only has its own entry in a few dictionaries, but I was able to find the phrase listed under 烏滸 in all the dictionaries I checked.  So maybe start by looking up 烏滸 instead of the whole phrase?

Comment: "Crazy decision" or something?

Answer (score 3):

It means "absurd thing," "absurdity."

- おこ came from an Old Japanese adjective をこ-なり which means "stupid, absurd."
  It only survives in set phrases such this one.

  をこなり: [Weblio古語辞典: をこなり](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%92%E3%81%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A)
- 沙汰 is a Modern Japanese word, and in this case simply means "thing."

  狂気の沙汰 crazy thing (crazy situation, deed and so on)

Answer (score 1):

It means: Impertinence, Absurdity